# PagedList cannot be resolved to a type cannot be resolved to a type while using spring social

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-social

I am building a simple app using spring and hibernate and I am trying to connect it with facebook using spring social.I am initializing my app without using xml files.I have read about spring social from its official site.But this is not working me at all.While I am trying to use code it is giving me the error "PagedList cannot be resolved to a type"
Exception

```
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/social/ApiBinding
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
```

My Controller class is

```
    package net.codejava.spring.controller;

import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import net.codejava.spring.dao.UserDAO;
import net.codejava.spring.model.User;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.social.facebook.api.Facebook;
import org.springframework.social.facebook.api.Post;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private Facebook facebook;
    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView checkLogin() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("LoginForm");
        return model;       
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/fb", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView fbLogin() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("facebook");
        return model;       
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/submit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView processCredential(@RequestParam("username")String username,@RequestParam("password")String password) {
        String message = "Invalid credentials";
        if(!username.equals("")&&!password.equals(""))
        {
            if(username.equals(username)&&password.equals(password)){
                message = "Welcome" +username+"!!!!";
            }
        }
     return new ModelAndView("result","message",message);   
    }
    @RequestMapping("/list")
    public ModelAndView handleRequest() throws Exception {
        List<User> listUsers = userDao.list();
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("UserList");
        model.addObject("userList", listUsers);
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView newUser() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("UserForm");
        model.addObject("user", new User());
        return model;       
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView editUser(HttpServletRequest request) {
        int userId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        User user = userDao.get(userId);
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("UserForm");
        model.addObject("user", user);
        return model;       
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView deleteUser(HttpServletRequest request) {
        int userId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        userDao.delete(userId);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");      
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveUser(@ModelAttribute User user) {
        userDao.saveOrUpdate(user);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
    }
    @Inject
    public HomeController(Facebook facebook) {
        this.facebook = facebook;
    }
      @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String helloFacebook(Model model) {
            if (!facebook.isAuthorized()) {
                return "redirect:/connect/facebook";
            }

            model.addAttribute(facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile());
            PagedList<Post> homeFeed = facebook.feedOperations().getHomeFeed();
            model.addAttribute("feed", homeFeed);

            return "hello";
        }

}
```

My ApplicationContectConfig class is where I am declaring properties file of Facebook

```
    package net.codejava.spring.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import net.codejava.spring.dao.UserDAO;
import net.codejava.spring.dao.UserDAOImpl;
import net.codejava.spring.model.User;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("net.codejava.spring")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ApplicationContextConfig {
    @Bean(name = "viewResolver")
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }


    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testing");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("4261");

        return dataSource;
    }


    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        return properties;
    }
    private Properties getFacebookProperties(){
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("spring.social.facebook.appId", "809280815833386");
        properties.put("spring.social.facebook.appSecret","24035c462c9d1fca367ff813436b15d8");

        return properties;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
        sessionBuilder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        sessionBuilder.addAnnotatedClasses(User.class);
        return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(
            SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(
                sessionFactory);

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "userDao")
    public UserDAO getUserDao(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        return new UserDAOImpl(sessionFactory);
    }
}
```

I have putted my Facebook properties file under src/main/resources
Please provide me the solution

Answer (score 0):

The exception you show says nothing about PagedList. But either the exception you mention or the exception you show can be explained as a classpath issue. From what you've said and shown, it seems that your runtime classpath is missing the Spring Social libraries. I can't explain why that is, though, because I don't know how you're building or running the application. If there's a GitHub repo I can look at, that might be useful. Otherwise I'm just guessing.